# Consulta select con eloquent en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy empezando con Laravel y tengo dos entidades simples que son `users` y `notas`, que se relacionan de la siguiente manera:

**Users**

```
public function notes()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Note');
}
```

**Notes**

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Ahora, dentro de mi controlador de notas con eloquent, me gustaría devolver todos los registros que tengo en la tabla de notas, pero en lugar de recibir el `id` del usuario en cada registro, quisiera devolver el nombre de este. ¿Hay algo que tengo que especificar en la relación de ambas entidades o simplemente debería ajustar algo en mi consulta como un join? ¿O en eloquent existe otra manera de hacerlo? En este momento estoy usando esto:

```
$notes = Note::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

Recuperas todas las notas y las muestras con un foreach:

```
$notes = Note::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('user')->get();
```

Para ver el nombre del usuario:

```
foereach($notes as $note){
     echo $nota->id .' => '. $nota->desc .' => '.$nota->user->nombreUser;
}

//Donde *nombreUser es el nombre de la columna en la que guardas el nombre de usuario en la tabla users.
```

Para devolver JSON:

```
return $notes->toJson();
```

Este código mostrará en pantalla el id de la nota, su descripción y el nombre del usuario.

Comment: gracias por responder, esta es la única manera de hacerlo? por que me gustaría tener todos estos registros para poder devolverlos en json

Comment: A ver, todos los registros están en $notes. Para pasar $notes a JSON tienes que hacer $notes->toJson(). He editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

en la documentacion de laravel puedes ver el ejemplo
[Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)
y para devolver json, puedes hacerlo con response.

```
$notesWithUSer = Note::with('user:name')->get();
return response()->json(['notes' => $notesWithUSer]);
```